# Renewing section with bfseries and makeuppercase on LyX

Tags: sectioning, lyx, capitalization

I want to define a new section style with the following

```
\renewcommand\section{%
  \@startsection{section}{1}
                {\z@}%
                {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}%
}
```

But whenever I try a \MakeUppercase

```
                {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\MakeUppercase}%
```

I get an error "File does not exist". If, instead, I place a \uppercase

```
                {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\uppercase}%
```

The section title at the ToC is not uppercase. Any ideas on this?

Minimal working example (MWE):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter

%Setting section style
\renewcommand\section{%
  \@startsection{section}{1}
                {\z@}%
                {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}% normal size, boldface
}

%Setting subsection
\renewcommand\subsection{%
  \@startsection{subsection}{2}
                {\z@}%
                {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                {\normalfont\normalsize\uppercase}% normal size, uppercase
}

%Redefining sub-subsection
\renewcommand\subsubsection{%
  \@startsection{subsubsection}{3}
                {\z@}%
                {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                {\normalfont\normalsize\MakeUppercase}% normal size, uppercase
}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\section{This should be capitalized here and at ToC}
\subsection{Anything}
\subsubsection{Anything else}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to surround the redefinition with `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother`. Without that, the `@` is causing problems. See [What do `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` do?](http://goo.gl/HYwLd)

Comment: Only scrambles the rest of the things that are settle ;)
Without the \MakeUppercase, it works just fine.
I just can't get \MakeUppercase and \bfseries together

Comment: Could pleas post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that you obtain from exporting your code to a `.tex` file? It's difficult to assess the problem based on the current information since a MWE wrapped the way I suggested works fine for me.

Comment: Done that... unfortunately it's a bit big.

Comment: Unfortunately you placed `\MakeUppercase` with `\subsection` and then you use `\section` in your document. Of course there will be no uppercase then. Fix that and you should be golden.

Comment: Werner, I didn't place `\MakeUppercase` at `\section` because it fails to build in LyX. :)
But you can be sure I tried that before.

Answer (score 1):

You have to redefine `\l@section`, which is the macro responsible for typesetting the section entry in the table of contents.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
%Setting section style
\renewcommand\section{%
  \@startsection{section}{1}
                {\z@}%
                {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\MakeUppercase}%
}

%Setting subsection
\renewcommand\subsection{%
  \@startsection{subsection}{2}
                {\z@}%
                {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
%                {1sp}% No space after subsubsections
                {\normalfont\normalsize\MakeUppercase}% normal size, boldface
}

%Redefining sub-subsection
\renewcommand\subsubsection{%
  \@startsection{subsubsection}{3}
                {\z@}%
                {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}% normal size, medium
}
\renewcommand*\l@section[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\z@
    \addpenalty\@secpenalty
    \addvspace{1.0em \@plus\p@}%
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      \MakeUppercase{#1}\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{This should be capitalized here and at ToC}

Anything

\end{document}
```

I've removed all the inessential bits in your code, just reducing to the redefinition of section titles and of `\l@section`. Add back what you need.

Comment: I still get the same error "File does not exist" with the `\MakeUppercase` here `{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\MakeUppercase}`. The log reads: _Systemcall: 'pdflatex  "teste.tex"' finished with exit code 1_ 
If I remove it (and maintain the l@section part) I get lots of "Undefined sequence" errors.

Comment: @Cyberz "File does not exist" is not a message issued by TeX/LaTeX.

Comment: It is issued by LyX, as stated in the title and tags.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this doesn't work (originally stated in [this comp.text.tex thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.text.tex/4TUT38nYGeU)), is that `\MakeUppercase` and `\uppercase` both take arguments, and are not declarations (like `\bfseries`).

One respondent to the thread defined the following macro which gets around this problem:

```
\def\MIA@up{%
  \def\@M##1\par{10000 \MakeUppercase{##1}\par}}
```

A macro can be set off in a latex file between `\makeatother` and `\makeatletter` in the header.
This macro should be usable with your code in the same way that you tried to use `\MakeUppercase`, as follows:

```
\renewcommand\section{%
  \@startsection{section}{1}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\MIA@up}%
}
```

Note that the version of this macro that I ended up using to solve the same issue (similar to the macro above, with the addition of some size adjustments and `\centering`, but defined using `\def` instead of `\renewcommand`) are all defined in a `.dtx` file which I compile to a `.cls` file and load with `\usepackage{}`.  There may be minor adjustments necessary to do it all in the header of a latex file.